# Can you mock an object that implements an interface AND an abstract class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Is it possible to use [Moq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moq) to mock an object that implements an interface and abstract class?

I.e.:

```
public class MyClass: SomeAbstractClass, IMyClass
```

Can you mock this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mock any interface, and any abstract or virtual members. That's basically it.

This means that the following are absolutely possible:

```
var imock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
var aMock = new Mock<SomeAbstractClass>();
```

If the members inherited from SomeAbstractClass aren't sealed, you can also mock MyClass:

```
var mcMock = new Mock<MyClass>();
```

Whether this makes sense or not depends on the implementation of MyClass. Let's say that SomeAbstractClass is defined like this:

```
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass
{
    public abstract string GetStuff();
}
```

If the GetStuff method in MyClass is implemented like this, you can still override it:

```
public override string GetStuff()
{
    return "Foo";
}
```

This would allow you to write:

```
mcMock.Setup(x => x.GetStuff()).Returns("Bar");
```

since unless explicitly sealed, GetStuff is still virtual. However, had you written GetStuff like this:

```
public override sealed string GetStuff()
{
    return "Baz";
}
```

You wouldn't be able to mock it. In that case, you would get an exception from Moq stating that it's an invalid override of a non-virtual member (since it's now `sealed`).

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really make sense. Moq can be used to mock abstract classes and interfaces. Since `MyClass` is neither then you cannot create a mock of it.
I don't think this is a problem though, since consumers of your MyClass instance will probably be expecting a `SomeAbstractClass` or an `IMyClass` instance and not a `MyClass` instance. If indeed they expect a `MyClass` instance, then you need to make some abstraction on top of it. This can be achieved by either having `SomeAbstractClass` implement the `IMyClass` interface, or by having the `IMyClass` interface expose the methods and properties of `SomeAbstractClass`.

Comment: I think his question did make sense that he was asking is possible to mock the *equivalent* MyClass object in his question

Comment: No, because in that case the correct question should have been: Can I use Moq to mock any concrete class? The answer would simply have been no. As far as I know Rhino mocks can do this though.