# ICollection in class

Tags: c#, oop

I come across the codes below:

```
public class Basket
{
    public Guid BasketId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }

    public Basket()
    {
        BasketItems = new List<BasketItem>();
    }
}
```

The part I do not quite understand is that why would we put

```
public virtual ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public virtual List<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
```

One reason I can think of is that when this class is inherited, we can override BasketItems with different types?

What are other reasons of doing so?

Comment: entity framework might be supplying a non-list implementation.

Comment: what does that mean @Daniel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding concrete types when possible is normally a good design practice.  It actually buys you a lot of strong advantages which are well documented in the Dependency Inversion Principle of SOLID - [SOLID Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Long story short, not putting yourself into a corner is good design because it allows the user to extend the property as they see fit and it lowers maintenance because, as an author, you don't have to create a new class type for every implementation of ICollection.

Another big benefit here is unit testing.  Avoiding concrete types makes it a lot easier to mock dependencies in unit tests.  This leads to test being smaller and more precise.  There's a good explanation here of the benefits for more info - [How do interfaces making unit testing and mocking easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370166/how-do-interfaces-making-unit-testing-and-mocking-easier)

Answer (score 3):

Because `BasketItems` doesn't *need* to be a list. Notice that the setter is public. It can also be overridden, as you pointed out.

It's essentially saying, as long as `BasketItems` is a collection of `BasketItem`, that's all we need to know. We don't care *how* the collection is implemented.

Comment: I suspect the public setter is a mistake, or they wouldn't initialize it in the constructor. If you leave a public setter lying around, you need to be prepared to handle `null`s.

Answer (score 1):

one more thing: `ICollection` is usually used in DataEntity for many-many/one-many relationships as well. You can refer (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) is a list of object that needs to be iterated through and modified.