# How to mock a function call on a concrete object with Moq?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

How can I do this in Moq?

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
Fake(bar.PrivateGetter).Return('whatever value')
```

It seems I can only find how to mock an object that was created via the framework. I want to mock just a single method/property on a concrete object I've created.

In TypeMock, I would just do `Isolate.WhenCalled(bar.PrivateGetter).Returns('whatever value')`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only TypeMock Isolator (and perhaps Moles) can perform these stunts. Normal dynamic mock libraries can [only mock virtual and abstract members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972831/to-mock-an-object-does-it-have-to-be-either-implementing-an-interface-or-marked/1973482#1973482).

Comment: Good to Know - wish there was more info on Moles out there - haven't heard anything on it at all yet as far as people using it here on SO

Comment: FWIW, here's the official site: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Comment: That Moq cannot do this is simply not true anymore.

Comment: @MushinNoShin Oh, I didn't know that! Can you provide a link?

Comment: Check the most upvoted answer in this question :)  It only works if there's a parameterless constructor available however, which is the case for this question.

Comment: @MushinNoShin Yes, and make sure to also read the comments from the OP: "This didn't work". That answer explains how to Moq virtual members, whereas the OP asks about private members. The link in my (accepted) answer explains what is technically possible.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Ah, you're right, I guess I glossed over the `bar.PrivateGetter` part.  Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

You should use Moq to create your Mock object and set CallBase property to true to use the object behavior.

From the Moq documentation:
CallBase is defined as “Invoke base class implementation if no expectation overrides the member. This is called “Partial Mock”. It allows to mock certain part of a class without having to mock everything.

Sample code:

```cs
    [Test]
    public void FailintgTest()
    {
        var mock = new Moq.Mock<MyClass>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Number).Returns(4);
        var testObject = mock.Object;
        Assert.That(testObject.Number, Is.EqualTo(4));
        Assert.That(testObject.Name, Is.EqualTo("MyClass"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void OKTest()
    {
        var mock = new Moq.Mock<MyClass>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Number).Returns(4);
        mock.CallBase = true;
        var testObject = mock.Object;
        Assert.That(testObject.Number, Is.EqualTo(4));
        Assert.That(testObject.Name, Is.EqualTo("MyClass"));
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public virtual string Name { get { return "MyClass"; } }

        public virtual int Number { get { return 2; } }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Makes TypeMock look more and more tempting though. Ugh!

Comment: This didn't work - it gave error message on the mock.Setup() line (in second example) "Test method CRMFundOfFundPluginsUnitTest.FoFPluginBaseTest.SetMissingTargetValuesTest1 threw exception:  System.ArgumentException: Invalid setup on a non-overridable member:
m => m.InputTargetDE.".

Any idea why?

Comment: Make sure the methods you are mocking are virtual so Moq will be able to override them.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. -- This calls base methods, but it requires that you let Moq create the object. -- The scenario that the OP showed has something externally creating the mock object.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question maybe, but it is close enough for many situations and solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Moles can also replace private methods as long as the types on the signature are visible. So in this case, it would look like this:

```
MFoo bar = new MFoo { // instantiate the mole of 'Foo'
    PrivateGetterGet = () => "whatever value" // replace PrivateGetter {get;}
};
Foo realBar = bar; // retrive the runtime instance
...
```

If you are looking for more information on Moles, start with the tutorials at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/documentation.aspx.