# ASP.NET MVC unit test controller with HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test for my one controller to verify if a view was returned properly, but this controller has a basecontroller that accesses the HttpContext.Current.Session.  Everytime I create a new instance of my controller is calls the basecontroller constructor and the test fails with a null pointer exception on the HttpContext.Current.Session.  Here is the code:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{       
    protected BaseController()
    {
       ViewData["UserID"] = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];   
    }
}

public class IndexController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index.aspx");
    }
}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Retrieve_IndexTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string expectedViewName = "Index";

        IndexController controller = new IndexController();

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Should have returned a ViewResult");
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedViewName, result.ViewName, "View name should have been {0}", expectedViewName);
    }
```

Any ideas on how to mock (using Moq) the Session that is accessed in the base controller so the test in the descendant controller will run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [Typemock](http://site.typemock.com/), you can do this:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(()=>controller.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"])
.WillReturn("your id");
```

The test code will look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Retrieve_IndexTest()
{
    // Arrange
    const string expectedViewName = "Index";

    IndexController controller = new IndexController();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(()=>controller.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"])
    .WillReturn("your id");
    // Act
    var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Should have returned a ViewResult");
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedViewName, result.ViewName, "View name should have been {0}", expectedViewName);
}
```

Answer (score 72):

Unless you use Typemock or Moles, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972831/to-mock-an-object-does-it-have-to-be-either-implementing-an-interface-or-marked/1973482#1973482).

In ASP.NET MVC you are not supposed to be using HttpContext.Current. Change your base class to use [ControllerBase.ControllerContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.controllercontext.aspx) - it has a [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.httpcontext.aspx) property that exposes the testable [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) class.

Here's an example of how you can use Moq to set up a Mock HttpContextBase:

```
var httpCtxStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext();
controllerCtx.HttpContext = httpCtxStub.Object;

sut.ControllerContext = controllerCtx;

// Exercise and verify the sut
```

where `sut` represents the System Under Test (SUT), i.e. the Controller you wish to test.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of how to mock this with Moles please?

Comment: Definitely the way to go; Microsoft added HttpContextBase for this precise reason. Now if only Cache and FormsAuthentication were not sealed/static...

Answer (score 3):

Snippet:

```
var request = new SimpleWorkerRequest("/dummy", @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dummy", "dummy.html", null, new StringWriter());
var context = new HttpContext(request);
SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(context, new TestSession());
HttpContext.Current = context;
```

Implementation of TestSession():

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace m1k4.Framework.Test
{
    public class TestSession : IHttpSessionState
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> state = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        #region IHttpSessionState Members

        public void Abandon()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Add(string name, object value)
        {
            this.state.Add(name, value);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int CodePage
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public System.Web.HttpCookieMode CookieMode
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsCookieless
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public bool IsNewSession
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public bool IsSynchronized
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection Keys
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public int LCID
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public SessionStateMode Mode
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public void Remove(string name)
        {
            this.state.Remove(name);
        }

        public void RemoveAll()
        {
            this.state = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string SessionID
        {
            get
            {
                return "Test Session";
            }
        }

        public System.Web.HttpStaticObjectsCollection StaticObjects
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public object SyncRoot
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public int Timeout
        {
            get
            {
                return 10;
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                return this.state[name];
            }
            set
            {
                this.state[name] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use Rhino.Mocks, you can simply do this `SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, MockRepository.GenerateStub<IHttpSessionState>());` instead of implementing TestSession by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use an [ActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx) instead of a base class for this sort of thing

```
[UserIdBind]
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use the action filter approach I would then have to decorate every action with this attribute and with about 400 actions that isn't feasible

Comment: @user299592: No, you wouldn't.  You can apply it at class level (as per the example) and it will apply it to every action in that class.  If you think that's going to be more effort than mocking out a context for every test on every action (few or none of which actually use the field you're setting in the constructor), fair enough.

Comment: Your correct I didn't see it at the class level, but wouldn't the action filter still be called when instantiating the controller object?

Comment: @user299592: No, it wouldn't. The MVC framework would invoke it before and after each action, but your unit tests wouldn't invoke it at all. That's the beauty of ActionFilters: you can test them separately and only have to build mock/fake contexts when testing that one method, which in your case is very simple - one line, one or two tests at most. Your action tests shouldn't need to care because it is abstracted away.

Answer (score 1):

I'd checkout the ASP.NET-MVC book listed here -- toward the end, there is a good section on Mocking framewors --  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FreeASPNETMVCEBookNerdDinnercomWalkthrough.aspx