# Response Object is a null reference in my Controller's action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a webapp using ASP.NET MVC and C#. And I'm creating a unit test for this webapp using NUnit and Rhino Mock. My problem is that I have a Response object in my controller's action method and when I execute my unit test my test is failing because the Response object is a null reference.

Do I need to separate this Response object call in my actions or there is a better way to resolve this?

```
public ActionResult Login( string user, string password )
{
     Response.Cookies[ "cookie" ].Value = "ck";
     ...
     return View();
}
```

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

What the controller really lacks is its HttpContext. In a test method it should be added explicitly if needed:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // Assume the controller is created once for all tests in a setup method
    _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var result = _controller.Login("username", "verySaf3Passw0rd");

    // Asserts here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the annoying points where ASP.NET MVC is not as testable and loosely coupled as it could be. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497575/asp-net-mvc-unit-test-controller-with-httpcontext) for some suggestions how to mock the HTTP context objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a real response that my mock context returns like this...

```
    Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> mockSession;
    Mock<ControllerContext> mockContext;
    Mock<ISessionProvider> mockSessionProvider;
    HttpResponse testResponse;
    MyController controller;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        testResponse = new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null);
        mockContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Response).Returns(new HttpResponseWrapper(testResponse));
        controller = new MyController();
        controller.ControllerContext = mockContext.Object;
    }
```