# ASP.NET: Unit testing controller fails because default response is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a controller. `SomeController` inherits from `BaseController`. `BaseController` inherits from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`.

My NUnit tests fail because a property `Response` in `Controller` is always null when running my tests. My test currently looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetByFilter_ShouldReturnABadRequest_WhenModelStateIsInvalid()
{
    _sut.ModelState.AddModelError("SessionName", "Required");
    var result = _sut.GetByFilter(_mockedFilter);
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
}
```

`_sut` is set by `[SetUp]` with this method:

```
protected override void InitSut() => _sut =
        new SomeController(_mockedLogger, _mockedService, _mockedRepository, _mockedHtmlSanitizer);
```

The code that fails on tests but works fine when running looks like this:

```
Response.Headers.Add("RowCount", result.Count().ToString());
return Ok(result);
```

Seems I need to do something to have the BaseController set the Response. In production the Response is filled with an instance of `HttpDefaultResponse`, but Response is `readonly`, so no way to set this myself.

I have tried following testing guides like this, but without luck:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

What do I need to do to start my controllers correctly and thus pass my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `Response` property, create a custom response via

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, result);
```

then you can add headers as needed

```
response.Headers.Add("RowCount", result.Count().ToString());
```

and return this as a result.

```
IActionResult rtn = ResponseMessage(response);
return rtn;
```

You may need to set or mock the `Request` object in your unit tests.

Comment: This would only replace my problem with Response to Request. Request is also readonly so mocking is not an option, thus leaving me with the same problem.

Comment: Although this question has different answers pointed out in different places, I came across this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045637/5416602) by @Plank and that worked best for me. Giving real HttpContext to controller resolves Request and Response issue without changing the actual code.
`_controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();`