# c# mvc 5 Why is my session null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

So I'm working with the Twitter API. My code looks like this:

```
        public ActionResult AuthorizeTwitter()
    {            
        Response.Redirect(GetRequestToken());
        return View();
    }

    private string GetRequestToken()
    {
        var twitter = new Twitter(consumer, consumerSecret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret);
        twitter.BaseURI = requestUrl;
        var result = twitter.GetRequest("http://localhost:60707/Twitter/GetAccessToken");

        string[] resultArray = result.Split('&');
        twitter.RequestToken = resultArray[0].Split('=')[1];
        twitter.RequestTokenSecret = resultArray[1].Split('=')[1];

        var requestToken = Session["oauth_token"] = resultArray[0].Split('=')[1];            
        Session["oauth_secret"] = resultArray[1].Split('=')[1];

        string redirect = authorizeUrl + requestToken;
        return (redirect);
    }

    public ActionResult GetAccessToken()
    {

        string verifier = Request.Params["oauth_verifier"];
        string token = Request.Params["oauth_token"];
        string secret = Session["oauth_secret"].ToString();
        .....
    }
```

I set the `Session["oauth_secret"]` in my `GetRequestToken` method and when I debug I see it fine.

However, when I get down to `GetAccessToken`, that value is no longer there and Session is *null*. Why is this?

Also, a related question, should I be keeping these values in Session?

Are there any problems with doing this and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: [Do not use HttpContext.Current.Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119345/mvc-not-supposed-to-use-httpcontext-current-anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check about your accessToken of your twitter expired?
I think it has a limited time and after that you must get it again.
Think about automation get accessToken in amount of time.

Comment: I'm authorizing the user and trying to get an access token, so this isn't happening.