# Run controller action from tests with view involving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

How to run controller action from test?
Yes, simple `new MyController().TestAction()` kinda works and returns some of `ActionResult`'s, but actually there's no render actions performed and that's why I can't see any of view errors (and even the lack of view!).
`ActionResult::ExecuteResult` looks like a good point to start, but in requires `ControllerContext` at least and simple `new`king is not enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test an MVC controller with instantiation and action invocation from request content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089519/how-to-test-an-mvc-controller-with-instantiation-and-action-invocation-from-requ)

Comment: What you are looking for is an integration test and not a unit test. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089519/how-to-test-an-mvc-controller-with-instantiation-and-action-invocation-from-requ/42090980#42090980).

Comment: Why I can't just fetch result from action and catch exceptions?

Comment: Because razor is an engine that needs to be hosted before it can render a view. I've read that Razor is not a part asp.net-mvc framework I can't remember where the article is. This could explain why you can't see any view being rendered. I could be wrong but that is what I know. 

IMHO, I don't know if your idea could work but imagine how many dependencies you need to plumb before you can run a simple 'unit test' in the approach you want.