# Why does RedirectToAction give a NullReferenceException when unit testing controller method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I'm writing a unit test for a controller in .Net Framework 4.5.2 but I'm getting a NullReferenceException when this line is hit:

```
return RedirectToAction<MyController>(action => action.Edit(itemId), "Something");
```

However, when I change it (and nothing else) to

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Something", new { myId = itemId });
```

it works perfectly.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection configured in your project? That might be the reason.

For Unit test try to inject `HttpContext` in a mock controller object. Sample code is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2497618/218408

Comment: Yes, dependency injection is done using Unity. I've tried injecting the HttpContext, but no luck.

Comment: Could you figure out on which line or object is throwing the null reference?

Comment: It is definitely on the return line posted in the original question, but it seems that all the objects are initialized correctly. I also tried stepping into it whilst debugging, but it simply throws the exception.

Comment: Did you fix this? If so, what was the cause?