# How to mock delegates in moq

Tags: unit-testing, delegates, nunit, moq

I have a class implementation as below. MethodUnderTest() is the method which calls the delegate to update grid with some custom filter, with a callback function - UpdateGridCallback.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void UpdateGridDelegate(MyCustomFilters filter);
    public UpdateGridDelegate del;
    public MyCustomFilters filter;

    public void MethodUnderTest()
    {
        //.... some code...
        // For simplicity of example I am passing somename.. should be passing rows..

        // set status bar saying retriving data..

       del = new UpdateGridDelegate(UpdateGrid);
       del.BeginInvoke(filter, UpdateGridCallback, null);
    }

    public void UpdateGrid(MyCustomFilters filter)
    {
       // Upadte Grid with passed rows.
    }

    public void UpdateGridCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
       // callback .. do some action here.. like updating status bar saying - Ready
    }
}
```

I am using Nunit and Moq.delegate. MethodUnderTest() is the method under test. How do I mock the delegate which is being used in MethodUnderTest()?

I want to make sure that delegate was invoked (or callback was executed) from my NUnit test case.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mock it as long as you `new` it up inside `MethodUnderTest`. [You can only mock what you could also have written by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1973482/126014), but in this case, there's no way to get at `del` from the outside.

You'll need to change the design to pass it in from the outside. Since `del` is already a class field, it seems most natural to pass it via Constructor Injection:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void UpdateGridDelegate(MyCustomFilters filter);
    public UpdateGridDelegate del;
    public MyCustomFilters filter;

    public MyClass(UpdateGridDelegate del)
    {
        this.del = del;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Now you can mock it.