# How can I Moq Azure CertificateClient response and certificate thumbprint

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to unit test my service that does certificate validation. It compares a given thumbprint with one that on a certificate that's stored in Azure Key vault.
My code works fine, but now I'm trying to unit test it (with Moq).

In order to do my test, I need to access/moq the retrieved certificate's thumbprint (the certificate is an object of type `KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy`.
My issue is when I mock the certificate's `Properties` object, Moq isn't able to mock `X509Thumbprint` as the setter is internal.

I get the following error with the below code:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.X509Thumbprint
> Non-overridable members (here: CertificateProperties.get_X509Thumbprint) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

This is an extract of my unit test code:

```csharp
var azCertificateProps = new Mock<CertificateProperties>();
azCertificateProps.SetupGet(x => x.X509Thumbprint).Returns(testThumbprint); // Fails here
var azCertificate = new Mock<KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy>(azCertificateProps.Object);
```

For reference, this is the actual code (simplified) I'm trying to unit test

```csharp
public KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy ExpectedCertificate { get; set; }

public async Task<bool> ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return clientCertificate.Thumbprint == BitConverter.ToString(ExpectedCertificate.Properties.X509Thumbprint).Replace("-", "");
}
```

I've tried to instantiate the `KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy` object itself, but I still can't find a way to pass my thumbprint in any way.

Comment: As the message says, you can't change the behaviour of non-overridable members. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1973482/126014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception was actually not caused by the `internal` setter. It's because the way Moq works (and most other mocking frameworks) is by `override`-ing methods or properties. In dotnet, you can only override `virtual` things.

That's why commonly, Moq works great with Interfaces because everything is `virtual`. But with concrete Classes, you'll start running into these limitations.

Here's an example:

```
class Test { public int Prop {get; set;} }
class TestVirt { public virtual int Prop {get; set;} }

new Mock<Test>().SetupGet(x => x.Prop).Returns(1); // FAILS!
new Mock<TestVirt>().SetupGet(x => x.Prop).Returns(1); // works

// Same problems with non-virtual methods.
```

With classes, usually we just create an instance of it instead of mocking. But we already know it won't work for you because of the `internal` setter.

And this is where we pull out the arcane tome of `System.Reflection`, using the type system to give us a backdoor to an object's internals. We can even set `private` variables if we so desire, as long as we know its name.

```
var testThumb = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var certProps = new CertificateProperties("");

typeof(CertificateProperties)
  .GetProperty(nameof(certProps.X509Thumbprint))? // Get property by name,
  .SetValue(certProps, testThumb); // and set its value.

Debug.Assert(certProps.X509Thumbprint.SequenceEqual(testThumb));
```

<s>One downside to reflection is that we are getting class members using a `string` of its name. If the class provider decides to change its signature and removes the property, you will only find out during runtime instead of compile-time.</s>

Using `nameof()` will give you a string with the property name. With the added bonus that if the property disappears, the compiler can actually catch it as an error instead of finding out at runtime.

Comment: Beautiful, I followed your example using reflection and that worked. I think if MS renames this property, the app will need updating anyway as we read that property in a bunch of other places around. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @Maxime, my apologies, we could make the compiler catch the signature change by using `nameof()` instead of a hardcoded string. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: good point, thanks, I've updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else's benefit, this is the updated (simplified) code to mock the Azure Certificate with a thumbprint that I ended up using. Thanks to @NPras for the help.

```
var stringTumbprint = "2CCC4....940"; // obfuscated
var azCertificateProps = new CertificateProperties("test");
typeof(CertificateProperties).GetProperty(nameof(azCertificateProps.X509Thumbprint))?
     .SetValue(azCertificateProps, StringToByteArray(stringTumbprint));
var azCertificate = new Mock<KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy>(azCertificateProps);
```